# Cannot view Designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, designer

[image]

Please help! I can not view the Control Parameter Adjustment Form in my VB project, other three forms are normal.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the Designer.vb code:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Control_Parameter_Adjustment
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.GroupBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
        Me.Label31 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
......
End Class
```

Comment: *Why* can't you "view the Control Parameter Adjustment Form"? Is there some kind of error?

Comment: Also, keep in mind, the designer executes code called when setting up the UI, so anything in your form setup that should not get called should be wrapped with `If Not DesignMode Then .... End If`

Comment: There's a problem with your `.Designer` file... Post the code for `Control Parameter Adjustment.Designer.vb`.... As of right now it is ***treating it as a class and NOT a Form***.

Comment: @Xi Wang it seems there are spaces in your class, you can't have spaces in them. Did you modify these? For example: `Control Parameter Adjustment` ***should be `Control_Parameter_Adjustment`... Your designer file does have the `_` in the name but your class in the tree doesn't show these... You are also missing `Me.SuspendLayout()` in the `InitializeComponent` sub and `Me.ResumeLayout(False)`...

Comment: @Zaggler, but for the rest of forms it contains "-" in code, but does not contains "-" in designer name. Those are working correct.

Comment: Share the whole code of your class and the designer file.

Comment: @XiWang also you are missing all of your `Friend WithEvents` for your controls... this is an issue as well...

Comment: The problem isn't necessarily the `*.Designer.vb` file, it could also be the project file. Try removing the form and its files from the project _**(but not from disk!)**_ and then re-import them to the project.

Comment: @VisualVincent I already re-import several times, but it is still missing.

Comment: And there are no errors in your code?

Comment: I find the problem, because I comment out  all my code, after uncomment I can view the Designer! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

At first, I apologize for my bad english.

This worked for me: If you add an empty form to your project, you can double clik on it, and you can see the following:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

End Class
```

You can't see that class definition in the other form, probably because this class have dissapeared (I can't explain you why).

Also and probably, you can find the form_Load event in the form code.

Simply rewrite this class, changing the Form Name in class definition. Then, you can see the designer. The icon also change.